# How do I create a flask login page with peewee?

Tags: python, flask, peewee

**Why I'm here**

I'm looking to make a simple flask login authentication system that uses peewee and flask_login's login_required module. I've gotten it to the point where everything seems to be working except for the authentication with "login_user()" and check the form for the correct fields. Server-side, it looks like the requests go through. However, when I submit on my webpage, nothing happens except for the POST 200 code in my console.

I've tried imputing peewee directly into my app.py and manually loading a database user into the required sections, and it successfully redirected to the next page. When I tried this though, it still wasn't authorized on the `@login_required` page, and even if it was it would have always done so automatically.

**File scheme:**

```
app.py
 UserManager.py
 Users.db 
 Temlates/
    login.html
```

**app.py**

```py
from form import *
from flask import *
from UserManager import *
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, login_user, logout_user, UserMixin

# Host config
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
hostname = host + str(port)

# App config
app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
app.secret_key = 'dev'

# Routing
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return get_username(id)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if username == get_username(username) and password == get_password(password):
            login_user(get_username(username))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout_page():
    logout_user()
    return "Logged Out"

@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return "Authenticated"

# Run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(' * Testing Server', flush=True)
    app.run(host, port, debug=True)
```

**UserManager.py**

```py
from peewee import *
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin

db = SqliteDatabase(
'C:/path/to/Users.db')

class User(Model, UserMixin):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.create_tables([User], safe = True)

def create_user(username, password):
    try:
        User.create(
        username=username,
        password=generate_password_hash(password))
    except IntegrityError:
        print("User already exists")

def delete_user(user_id):
    try:
        user = User.get(User.username == user_id)
        user.delete_instance()
        print(user_id + " deleted")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        print('no such user')

def list_users():
    try:
        print('Users: '),
        for person in User.select():
            print(person.username),
    except:
        print('no users')

def remake_user(username, password):
    delete_user(username)
    create_user(username, password)
    print(username + ' remade')

def get_username(data):
    return User.get(User.username == data)

def get_password(data):
    return User.get(User.password == data)

db.close()
```

**login.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>login page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Please login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="" method="post">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
          request.form.username }}">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
          request.form.password }}">
         <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code 200 means that everything works. The problem seems to come from your code while you're trying to return a Response in login_page(). Check if the conditions are well executed. You do not seem to return anything or redirect the user. You should also take a look at this [example](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/blob/master/flasklogin.py)

Comment: I was aware that a 200 code meant it was okay, but that was all I really knew. With some slight adjustments (host configuration and updated import names) to the example you game me, I was able to make something close to what I wanted. Thank you! With this, I'll make tweaks it 'till I'm happy with using it in my environment.